# Can I make ActiveRecord behave without an automatic ID column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to have a tree table in a Rails 3.2 application that is a copy of a table that an API I am using accesses from another site. This data already exists there, and it already has it's own `id` and `parent_id` columns. I'm going to use the `ancestry` gem to access it.

I will need to refresh this table with that data from time to time. As such, I would like the pre-defined `id` column to be the id for ActiveRecord purposes. Other than the refresh of the data, there will never be any inserts to this table, only updates.

My question is, can I simply redefine the `id` field in the model to this predefined `id`, and let the MySQL "id" field just sit there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable id field like this

```
create table :blah, id: false
```

Or You can disable id as a primary key.

```
create_table :blah, id: false do |t|
  t.integer :id, options: 'PRIMARY KEY'
end
```